# Twilio - Tracking clients who press button in template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-api

I am sending messages on Whatsapp using a Twilio number. I created a template with a "call to action" button, which redirects to a website. Is it possible to know which clients clicked on the link (on the button)?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I understand, you can set a link for the button that will be the same for each message. So you can't track based on the link that they click, but if they are logged in on their device, you could detect that they landed on that link and attribute it to their account.